# Where can I find documentation/tutorial(s) for Mutagen? (Python)

Tags: python, mp3

After asking this question: 
[How do I read album artwork using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171565/how-do-i-read-album-artwork-using-python)

I got 'stuck' as it were.

I have spent forever looking for documentation online but haven't come across any. I know that a lot of responses suggest reading the internal docstrings etc. but to be honest this is the first time I've come across a library without adequate documentation and its (to be honest) a little daunting.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things you might try.  [Pydoc](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html) makes it easy to navigate the contents of docstrings for a given project.  Assuming you have installed mutagen globally or in a virtualenv, this should start a webserver where you can browse locally:

```
% pydoc -p 8080
# then navigate to http://localhost:8080/mutagen.html to see the docs
```

Assuming you've already used the information in the [tutorial on the mutagen wiki](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/wiki/Tutorial), I'd suggest browsing the source code for [some projects which use mutagen](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/#Real_World_Use).  For example [used by the Gnome Listen player](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~listen-devel/listen/devel/view/head:/src/easymp3.py), [quodlibet tagger/player](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#0lLXERcdLsI/quodlibet/tests/test_formats__id3.py&q=mutagen%20package%3ahttp://quodlibet.googlecode.com&sa=N&cd=5&ct=rc), etc.